# get Microsoft Teams recorded videos

Tags: api, office365, microsoft-teams

We need an automated solution to store in Microsoft Teams recorded videos on our own platform. Microsoft anounced last year, that they will integrate this feature in the Teams API, but I can't find futher imormation on this topic.

Does anyone know how to this this?
Or is there an other way to access the recordings?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can get call records using get call record API. Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: thanks for the information. But in this API I only find information about the recording, not the recording itself, for example something like a link. we need the real recording to save it in another location

Comment: Currently we don't have API which provide a recording link. You can get the recorded video in Steam please check https://msit.microsoftstream.com/studio/videos

Answer (score 0):

You can get call records using get call record API. Could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Currently we don't have API which provide a recording link. You can get the recorded video in Steam please check https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/microsoft-stream